# Button does not change color on click in phone gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new in phone gap and this is my code

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" align="center" style="margin-left: 4px;" >
  <div class="ui-block-a" data-role="content" style="margin-top: 10px;height: 107px;width: 120px;" align="center">
<a data-role="button" id="btnMyVisit"  data-theme="my-site" style="height: 107px;width: 120px;" data-transition="none"  data-mini="true"  data-prefetch="true" href="#myVisit">
<img src="img/MyVisit.png" id="myvisitid" style="vertical-align: middle;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px; height: 112px;width: 120px;"> </a>
            </div>
```

**My question is that** whenever i click the button it does not change its color before visiting the link...i want it to change its color before visiting so that user could know that he just clicked on this link.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix this using css:

```
.btnMyVisit:active {
  // Change something, eg the background color:
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add the class "ui-btn-active" to the button that the user clicks and that will change the color. Then just override the "ui-btn-active" css style to set it to the color you want.

Comment: i tried but the button is not flashing before visiting the link..it just simply visits the page and does not show any color while clicking

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code according to ur req. , i m sure this will help u out.

```
function changePage(divId, pageTransition, reverseTransition, changeHash){
var pageTransition1 = typeof(pageTransition) != 'undefined' ? pageTransition : 'none';  
var reverseTransition1 = typeof(reverseTransition) != 'undefined' ? reverseTransition : false;
var changeHash1 = typeof(changeHash) != 'undefined' ? changeHash : true;

    $.mobile.changePage( '#'+divId, {
    transition: pageTransition1,
    reverse: reverseTransition1,
    changeHash: changeHash1
    });

}

$( "#btnMyVisit" ).click(function() {
//this changes the color of your link...
$(this).css('color','red');



setTimeout(function (){               

    //something you want delayed by 3 sec   
    // now write code for the event you wanna perform
    changePage('myVisit', 'slideup', true, true);

   }, 3000);


});
```

Also,

change href="#myVisit" to href = "javascript:void(0)" in your anchor tag.